# Is it possible to set the prompt to a variable - MySql - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like to change the prompt to my mariadb or mysql client.

I would like the prompt to be the contain of a variable like `report_host` or more, to something that can change like `default_master_connection`.

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK MySQL prompt cannot be set to MySQL variables (Global or Session). The only options that can be used are documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html (look towards the end of the documentation page for a full list).

Answer (score 1):

Several ways.

Set it manually:

```
mysql> prompt Foo>
PROMPT set to 'Foo> '
Foo>
```

Environment variable:

```
root@ironforge:~# export MYSQL_PS1="Foo> "
root@ironforge:~# mysql -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 195
Server version: 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Foo>
```

You can also use variables to add things like the database name (`\d`), hostname (`\h`) etc to the prompt. A full list is available [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html).

Comment: sorry, but I want the prompt to follow some mysql variables.  I just don't know what the variable will be BEFORE I launch mysql or mariadb, but it may change often during working sessions.